# Access control in masterpage from shared function of same masterpage

Tags: vb.net, master-pages

I'm calling a shared function of a masterpage from a content page. In that shared function I want to access a control in the masterpage, but I don't know how.

**main.master**

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltCurrency" runat="server" />
```

**main.master.vb**

```
Partial Public Class main
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Public Property CurrencyText() As String
    Get
        Return ltCurrency.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value <> "" Then
            ltCurrency.Text = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function DoSomething() As String  
    ltCurrency.Text="SOME TEXT" 'throws error: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.    

    CurrencyText="SOME TEXT" 'this property isn't found at all
```

'I also tried instantiating a new class of the current masterpage:
Ctype(main,Masterpage).CurrencyText

```
End Function


End Class
```

From page1.aspx I call:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    main.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth (I don't know why you need to make it shared), you can use `HttpContext` to get the reference to your page and from there to your master:

```
Public Shared Function DoSomething() As String
    Dim myPage = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
    If myPage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim myMaster As main = TryCast(myPage.Master, main)
        If myMaster IsNot Nothing Then
            myMaster.ltCurrency.Text = "SOME TEXT" 
            myMaster.CurrencyText = "SOME TEXT"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I thought I needed to make the funtion shared to be able to call it from my regular content page? If I remove the "Shared" part, the function is not available to me from the content page.
But your solution works :)

Comment: @Floran: If you want to call the method from the content-page, you need to cast the `Master` property of the page to the actual type of your `MasterPage`. Have a look at my code since i'm doing it already.

Comment: Ah I see. But when I declare it as a shared method I can access the method directly via the masterpage classname, without having to cast it to masterpage first. Is there a best practice here?

Comment: @Floran: Best-practise is to make it an instance method since the `Shared` mistakenly suggests that the method could also be used without a  Http-Context, actually it accesses controls that exist only during a Page's Life Cycle that uses this master.

Comment: @Floran: Why do you need to call the method from the content-page at all? You could also handle `Page_Load` in the master and call it from there.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This answer is great but how can it be used to access a masters masterpage? (myPage.Master.Master, main)?

Comment: @Obsidian: VB.NET or C#? You could use a loop: `If myPage IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim master = myPage.Master
            Dim myMaster = TryCast(master.Master, ERPMaster)
            While master.Master IsNot Nothing AndAlso myMaster Is Nothing
                master = master.Master
                myMaster = TryCast(master, ERPMaster)
            End While
            ' ... '
        End If`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. Please could you help with my error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728261/how-to-access-a-top-level-master-page-sub-from-within-a-nested-page

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create an event in your content page.

```
Public Event DoSomething(sender as object, myString as String)
```

Step2: On your mainpage add an eventhandler to the event that you just created in your content page.

```
Addhandler contentPage.DoSomething, AddressOf ChangeCurrentText
```

Step3: In the handler do whatever you would like to do.

```
Private Sub ChangeCurrentText(sender, text)
ltCurrency.Text = text
End Sub
```

Step4: Raise the event in the content page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RaiseEvent DoSomething(ME, "BLAH BLAH")
End Sub
```