# How to access a top level master page sub from within a nested page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nested, master-pages

**MASTER PAGE STRUCTURE**

```
TOP MASTER
    PAGE MASTER "TopMaster.ErrorMsg(ErrMsg) Here throws NO error"
        PAGE "TopMaster.ErrorMsg(ErrMsg) Here throws error"
```

I am unable to gain access to the top level class from the base page.

**TOP MASTER ASPX**

```
<asp:Literal ID="litMsg" runat="Server"/>
```

**PAGE.VB**

```
Partial Public Class BasePage
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TopMaster.ErrorMsg(ErrMsg) 
    "Error BC30451: TopMaster is not declared it may be inaccessible due to its protection level."
  End Sub

End Class
```

**MASTER.VB**

```
Partial Public Class PageMaster
  Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

End Class
```

**TOP MASTER.VB**

```
Partial Public Class TopMaster
  Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

  Public Shared Sub ErrorMsg(ErrMsg As String)
    Dim myPage = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)

    If myPage IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim master = myPage.Master
      Dim myMaster = TryCast(master.Master, TopMaster)
      While master.Master IsNot Nothing AndAlso myMaster Is Nothing
        master = master.Master
        myMaster = TryCast(master, TopMaster)
      End While

      myMaster.litMsg.Text = ErrMsg
    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't understand the error _"Error: Top Master is not declared"_. That should happen only if the type `TopMaster` is not declared or not acessible from wherever you use this class.

Comment: I agree. Your code worked fine when it was in the Pages master but cannot find it now it is in the master master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: now it's clear, make the class `Public`, otherwise you can't access it:

```
Partial Public Class TopMaster
```

<strike>You should show us the exact error message including stacktrace. It seems that the type `Top Master` is not declared which makes no sense since you are in the class `TopMaster`.</strike>

So i doubt that following fixes your core issue "Error: Top Master is not declared" but it might be useful anyway.

If you want to access that literal you should provide a property in your `TopMaster` like this:

```
Public Property ErrorMsg As String
    Get
        Return Me.litMsg.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.litMsg.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

On this way you can even change the control-type if you want without breaking the code. Its much better than to expose the control itself.

I guess you also  have to move the assignment from inside the loop to outside. You should also use `Dim myMaster = TryCast(master, TopMaster)` at the beginning instead of jumping directly to the page's master's master as you do with `TryCast(master.Master, TopMaster)`:

```
Public Shared Sub ErrorMsg(ErrMsg As String)
    Dim myPage = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)

    If myPage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim master = myPage.Master
        Dim myMaster = TryCast(master, TopMaster)
        While master.Master IsNot Nothing AndAlso myMaster Is Nothing
            master = master.Master
            myMaster = TryCast(master, TopMaster)
        End While
        myMaster.ErrorMsg = ErrMsg
    End If

End Sub
```

Otherwise you are only assigning the `ErrorMsg` if the master is the page's master's master's master or it's even more deeply nested.

Comment: Then show us the output window when you try to compile. It shows the exact compiler error including it's number. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx

Comment: I appreciate your help Tim. The error from the output window is as above.

Comment: @Obsidian: it's still not clear why you get the error. Where in your code do you use a variable or type `Top Master` (including the space). Have a look also at your aspx code.

Comment: Please see edits above. This is now the exact code I am using and shows every instance of TopMaster. The error is only thrown when trying to read the second master page.

Comment: I was optimistic but this does not solve the issue. If I move `TopMaster.ErrorMsg(ErrMsg) ` into the pageMaster.vb then the class is accessible.

Comment: @Obsidian: by always modifying your question you're making my answer obsolete. Add new informations but not apply all suggestions, otherwise people will wonder if i was a little bit drunk  when i wrote this ;)